# Weird Timeout on 4th HttpWebRequest in Multi-Threaded Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a multi-threaded console application acting as a server. The server spawns a new thread  every time a new client connects to the TcpListener:

```
//code copied from http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-  threaded-tcp-server
//blocks until a client has connected to the server
TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();  
//create a thread to handle communication with connected client
Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
```

The thread makes a number of HttpWebRequests using the following code:

```
public static HttpWebResponse HttpGet(string pRequestURI, string pArgs)
{
    string requestURI = string.Format("{0}?{1}", pRequestURI, pArgs);
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURI);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    return response;
}
```

The problem is that, I get a timeout on the **FOURTH** REQUEST. It is really weird and I cannot get the hang of it. The code worked just fine when it was in a single-threaded application. I am also making sure to close the response stream using:

```
response.Close();
```

The requestURI is correct, 'cause I tried copying and pasting it into my browser. Actually, it doesn't matter what the 4th request is (I've tried with different ones), I always get a timeout.

I guess it may be something related to thread-limits, but I really don't know how to solve it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify: you only have a single client, and it's the fourth request by the server that fails?  Or does the problem only manifest with more than one client?

Comment: @arx At the moment I have only a single client, an ASP.NET web application. Eventually, the server will have more clients, but at the moment I only have one.

Comment: It doesn't sound much like a threading problem.  You've only got two: the main thread which is idle waiting for another connection and the service thread, which doesn't have any other thread to interfere with.  Are you doing anything between making the web requests?  Are you closing a response before making the next request, or keeping them all open so you can process them together?

Comment: @arx Actually I have 3 threads 'cause it's not the main thread that's listening for the requests, but another listener thread spawned from it. I am closing the response prior to making another request. In fact I immediately process a response and then close it.

Comment: Is the main thread doing anything?

Comment: @arx At the moment, no. It just spans the listener thread. But in the future it will spawn another thread that will be performing some different processing. (Haven't gotten round to writing the code yet.)

Comment: So it still doesn't sound like a threading problem.  What I'd do is run the single threaded version again (to ensure nothing's changed on the other server), then do a diff between the single- and multi-threaded versions to ensure I hadn't inadvertently changed anything apart from the threading.

Comment: @arx I tried making the server (the console app) single threaded and it STILL failed, so it's definitely not a threading problem. I have re-copied the same code back to the web app (ASP.NET), and thus by-passing the use of sockets altogether, and the code works again. This was how it was originally. I'm baffled as to what the problem with the Console Application could be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of blood, sweat and tears, I managed to solve it.

It was a stupid mistake really, turns out there was this one place where I was **not closing the request**.

For some (unknown) reason, this does not affect the requests when made from a Web Application, but, when issuing the requests from a Console Application, timeout problems are encountered.

Thank you @arx for your help - much appreciated.

Comment: For me, I had to close the whole connection group using `request.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(request.ConnectionGroupName);` for every request I've made, after getting the response.

Answer (score 1):

request.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(request.ConnectionGroupName);
This line of code resolved my issue
Thanks